# When measuring the quantity of flux using $B \sin\theta$, how do you know which angle to use?

Tags: magnetic-fields, vectors, vector-fields

Let's say that you have a magnetic field passing through an area at an angle. For example:

[image: 1]

Thus the quantity of flux $\Phi$ can be calculated using $\Phi = BA \sin\theta$ (the equation in my textbook).

But how do we know what's the correct angle to use? Why can't we take, say, $180 - \theta$?

[image: 2]

Comment: It's the dot product between the magnetic field B and a vector normal to the surface A. Do you know the definition of dot product? How did you get $sin(\theta)$? Your book really says that?

Comment: [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093)
are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific 
computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader 
audience. If you intend to modify your question, please read the links above carefully before editing.

Comment: @josephh in which sense do you think this is a homework-like question? This is a genuine conceptual question. Its only drawback is some lack of clarity (starting from the presence of the  sin function).

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree. I don't think this is a homework question.

Comment: @josephh Please don't conflate the level of difficulty of the question and whether it is homework or not.

Comment: @VincentThacker I'm not conflating anything. I stand by my decision that this is a homework question.

Comment: Please stop using the book which says that flux is given by BAsinx because the correct formula is BAcosx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using that type of equation, just check if it gives sensible results when $\theta=0$, as sometimes it needs $\cos\theta$, depending on where the angle is measured from.

For the particular diagram in the question it needs $$\Phi = BA\cos\theta$$ to give maximum flux (instead of zero) when $\theta=0$.